# Showing $\int_0^s \int_0^u (F_1(u)-F_1(u-v)) f_1(u-v) e^{-v}\, dv\, du \leq \int_0^s \int_0^u (F_2(u)-F_2(u-v)) f_2(u-v) e^{-v}\, dv\, du$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

## Question

Let $F(s)$ be a cumulative distribution function (cdf) of a random variable on $[0,\infty)$ which only has an atom at $0$, i.e. $F(0) >0$ and for all $s>0$:$$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}F(s+h)=F(s).$$
Let $\bar{F}(s)=1-F(s)$ and $f = F'(s)$. Note that$$
F(0) = 1-\int_0^\infty f(s) ds.$$

Now define the following operation on $F$:
$$
HF(s)=\int_0^s \int_0^u (F(u)-F(u-v)) f(u-v) e^{-v}\, dv\, du.
$$
Now suppose $F_1,F_2$ are both cdfs as described above, and suppose for all $s$, $F_1(s) \leq F_2(s)$ and $F_1(0)=F_2(0)$, show that $HF_1(s) \leq HF_2(s)$ for all $s$.

## Thoughts

One can use Fubini to change the order of integration, the second part can then be solved by writing it as:
\begin{align*}
-\int_0^s \int_v^s F(u-v) f(u-v) \, du e^{-v}\, dv
&=
-\int_0^s\int_0^{s-v}F(u)f(u)\,du e^{-v}\,dv\\
&=-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^s \left( F(s-v)^2-F(0)^2 \right) e^{-v}\, dv.
\end{align*}
However we can not do something similar for the first part as here the argument of $F$ and $f$ are not the same..

## Partal Integration

As suggested in the answer, partial integration can be used to get rid of the density $f$. An alternative partial integration to use to simplify the first part is to note that the first part equals:
$$
\int_0^sF(u)\int_0^uf(u-v) e^{-v}dv du
$$
and then use partial integration on $\int_0^uf(u-v) e^{-v}dv$, integrating $f(u-v)$ and differentiating $e^{-v}$.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer but it's too long for a comment. You can 'solve' the remaining part of the integral using partial integration as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\def\d{\,\mathrm{d}}
\int_0^s \int_0^u F(u) f(u-v) e^{-v} \d v \d u 
&= \int_0^s \int_0^u F(u) f(v) e^{-(u-v)} \d v \d u \\
&= \int_0^s \int_0^u F(u) e^{-u} f(v) e^v\d v \d u \\
&= \int_0^s F(u) e^{-u} \left(F(u)e^u - F(0) - \int_0^u F(v) e^v \d v \right)\, \d u \\
&= \int_0^s F(u) \left(F(u) - F(0)e^{-u} - \int_0^u F(v) e^{-(u-v)} \d v \right)\, \d u \\
\end{align}
$$

Combined with the answer you found for the other half this might be enough to prove the full inequality.

Comment: I am currently looking into this. I have already tried some stuff with partial integration, but it was different from your suggestion.